# Anyone please tell me the difference between #filename and filename.html

Tags: html, url, anchor

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#filename">home</a>
<br/>
  <a href="filename.html">home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

please anyone clarify this.
when i click on home with #filename as href element it is not navigating to next page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#filename` is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It links into an element *in* the page.

`filename.html` is a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier). It is a link to a (usually) different page.

Given your example + a small change:

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#filename">home</a>
<br/>
  <a href="filename.html">home</a>
<br/>
 <span id="filename">The home</span>
</body>
</html>
```

`#filename` links to the `span` with `id="filename"`. If that `span` is not visible, the page will jump to it (but there will be no call to the server to refetch the page).

`filename.html` links to the html page in the same directory whose filename is `filename.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Say your website is www.website.com

`<a href="#filename">home</a>` will change the URL to www.website.com#filename but not actually refresh the page. If there happens to be an element with the attribute `name="filename"` the browser will jump to that element.

`<a href="filename.html">home</a>` will redirect the browser to www.website.com/filename.html

Answer (score 0):

`#filename` will take you to a given anchor (or element with the ID of `filename`) on the current page.

`filename.html` will take the user to the HTML file called `filename.html`.

Answer (score 0):

`#filename` is an anchor refering to something on the current page. `filename.html` is an URI and refers to a (most probably different)webpage.